# How to re-run aws data pipeline automatically on failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I created aws data pipeline but it fails when it's executed by cron schedule.

I have detailed post on [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266162) with pipeline definition that I'm using.

The question is: How can I re-run pipeline automatically on failure, so I don't have to login and re-run it manually?

Thanks,
Ernest

Answer (score 0):

Failed actions are automatically retried (3 times by default) after 5 minutes, no need for manual intervention.

May I ask if there is any reason to set `attemptTimeout": "120 SECONDS"`? I think your actions might be timing out because of this setting.

Comment: For some reason it wasn't going to second attempt it was just stuck in 1st with "TIMEOUT". I ended up using 'ondemand' pipeline instead of on schedule and have cron event call lambda (to activate pipeline).